# Display fragments with Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment

I'm confused how to open my different fragments by clicking on one Item in my navigation drawer.

In MainActivity I use the following Code:

```js
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment;

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_listview) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment, new ListFragment());
        ft.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_add_data) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_legal_information) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

First of all I want to try to open my ListFragment:

```js
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class ListFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    }
}
```

In my content main.xml I created the following fragment which should be replaced when clicking on the specific Items in the Navigation Drawer.

```html
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment" />
```

But it isnt working...

Can anyone help me?

Rastaman

Comment: Any errors? or the fragment is not replacing ?

Comment: No I used the Design tool to add my fragment_list fragment manually. And now i get it on screen but if I click on the "list" item in my navigation drawer I get the loading circle in the middle of the fragment and nothing happens.

Comment: have you tried adding or implemented other fragments?

Comment: Ahhh. Things are getting better. I added the AddDataFragment and now I can switch between Fragments. But The ListFragment is always in the background. I think that the list fragment is not replacing....
(the loading circle seems to be the ListView inside the ListFragment which didnt get any data)

Comment: Now I am able to switch between my 2 Fragments. But I think there is somesthing wrong with my listfragment xml. there is only the loading circle. And the second problem is that I have to use a "PlaceholderFragment" to prevent that the Fragments are laying over each other. But now my first screen is just white....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Change The name  of your fragment class ListFragment Because ListFragment is already Sub Class of Fragments in  **android.app** ***package*** android OS

Answer (score 2):

To get what you want try this ,I was also held up with this somewhat complex looking code but its more of a easy way to use

Here's detailed explanation and walk through to this issue: 
(Its seems Long But You can easily relate your work asap)

When you first create the Navigation Drawer Activity, there are 5 files we’ll look at:

- **MainActivity.java** - this is the code behind for everything in our app.
- **activity_main.xml** - this is the layout for the app including the nav drawer and an include for the app_bar_main.
- **app_bar_main.xml** - this is the layout with the toolbar (at the top), a floating action button (at the bottom right), and an include for content_main.
- **content_main.xml** - this is the layout for the content of the main page.
- **nav_header_main.xml** - this is the UI for the top part of the nav drawer.

**Step 1:**
 open up the **app_bar_main.xml**, comment out the include and add a new FrameLayout:

```
<!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->

<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/Fragment_container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

This FrameLayout is what we’ll use to load our fragments into.

**Step 2:**
Next, you’ll want to add a few fragments
To do so, right click on your project, or go to File –> New and from the Fragment list choose Fragment (Blank) or others

**Step 3:**
The next step is to load a fragment when the app first launches. Go to the **MainActivity**’s onCreate method and put the following in after the call to **setSupportActionBar**:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
Class fragmentClass = null;
fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
try {
    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

**Step 4:**

You’ll then need to add **OnFragmentInteractionListener** to the interfaces your **MainActivity** implements and also implement the **onFragmentInteraction** method.Like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener ,FragmentTwo.OnFragmentInteractionListener,FragmentThree.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

**Step 5:**
Finally, in the **onNavigationItemSelected** method, you can add the ability to load different fragments when menu items are tapped:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentThree.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Here I’m just loading one of the two fragments I’ve added to my app. Note that because I have two different fragments, I had to implement the interfaces for both FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener and FragmentTwo.OnFragmentInteractionListener.

That’s all you need to do to implement fragment loading in your Navigation Drawer. 
What the user taps a menu item, the drawer will slide back in smoothly and the new fragment will have already started / finished loading. This also prevents any possible jankiness that you could see when launching a new activity.

**EXTRA**
 One last thing to note is that if you switch to a different fragment and then rotate the device or cause another recreation of the activity, the code above will cause the first fragment to be reloaded. One easy way to deal with that is to wrap the fragment block in the onCreate method in a check to see if the **savedInstanceState** is not null like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        //Fragment load code
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code

```js
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment=null;
 FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_listview) {
       
       fragment= new ListFragment();
    

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_add_data) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_legal_information) {

    }
ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

```html
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/container" />
```

Comment: Error:(116, 37) error: variable fragment might not have been initialized

Comment: I added : 
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         Fragment fragment;
         FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         fragment = new ListFragment();

to initialize the standard Fragment as ListFragment. But it didnt work..

But the code in general seems to be correct. I can open my AddDataFragment this way. But I dont get the mistake witch the ListFragment...

Answer (score 0):

Mhmm I found an answer. But I am confused.
If I use:

```js
             if (id == R.id.nav_listview) {
                 fragment= new com.thomas.testapp.ListFragment();
```

It works. But I only have to use the package name if I want to open my ListFragment. Why?

Comment: There is an official class called "ListFragment". After renaming stuff works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to Create codes More Dynamic

first of all, if you have custom class to create Navigation Drawer, use listener to call methods from your activity
there is class call HomeFragment extends Fragment, so we have :

```
if(condition){
    fragment = new HomeFragment();
    // if there is Listener
    if(mListener != null){
        mListener.someMethod
    }
    // Other Settings And Codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



// ...



@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ...From section above...

    // Find our drawer view

    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);

    // Setup drawer view

    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

}



private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(

            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override

                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);

                    return true;

                }

            });

}



public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {

    // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked

    Fragment fragment = null;

    Class fragmentClass;

    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_first_fragment:

            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;

            break;

        case R.id.nav_second_fragment:

            fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;

            break;

        case R.id.nav_third_fragment:

            fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;

            break;

        default:

            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;

    }



    try {

        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }



    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();



    // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView

    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    // Set action bar title

    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

    // Close the navigation drawer

    mDrawer.closeDrawers();

}



// ...
```

}