# How to make applications with many fragments

Tags: java, android

I want to make application with a lot fragments and navigation drawer.
So I am starting a new project with `NavigationDrawerActivity` and I got nice place for my fragments:

[image]

Is it possible to use this place `<include>` where I have content main for put my fragments ?

From the android studio I received the automatically generated code: :

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
}
```

Can I create a logic here that will replace the automatically generated content main with my own fragment?

Comment: yes, why not. whatever you want, you can do

Comment: check it -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840769/managing-fragments-in-a-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/frame2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1" >
     </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

other way :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment frag1 = new Fragment();
ft.add(R.id.llfram, frag1, "fragment_1");

Fragment frag2 = new Fragment();
ft.add(R.id.llfram, frag2, "fragment_2");

ft.commit();
```